# How can I contact the examiner of an application about potential prior art?

Tags: prior-art, us20140272639, wo2011050437a1

In reference to the patent: [US 2014/0272639 A1](https://www.google.com/patents/US20140272639)

I have in the past (2010) filed and had patent application [PCT/CA2009/001540](http://www.google.com/patents/WO2011050437A1) approved, which is a device which makes carbon from carbon dioxide for the purpose of recycling it as carbon and carbon dioxide. This recycling technology has been promoted publicly since before 2010 and is an obvious development of the invention.

We are pursuing this technology commercially presently and this USPTO 
application covers what we have already accomplished.

I would like to contact the examiner of this application to ensure they are aware of my own prior art. How can I do that?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Patents! This is a community-run website to ask about the patent process or to help *find* Prior Art on US Patents or Applications. Unfortunately, we do not currently have a direct channel to the examiner so they will not get your message here. I've edited your question a bit to ask how you could get in contact with the examiner.

Comment: Are you asking about contacting the examiner of your application or someone else's application?

Answer (score 1):

Since the AIA went into effect, you may submit prior art online at the USPTO via a [3rd party submission](http://www.uspto.gov/patent/initiatives/third-party-preissuance-submissions) (refer to [this answer](https://patents.stackexchange.com/a/6409/14417)):

- [MPEP 1134](http://www.uspto.gov/web/offices/pac/mpep/s1134.html) Third Party Inquiries and Correspondence in a Published Application
- [MPEP 2205](http://www.uspto.gov/web/offices/pac/mpep/s2205.html) Content of Prior Art or Section 301 Written Statements

From [another related question](https://patents.stackexchange.com/a/5656/14417):

> The AIA 3rd party submission process window opens at publication and
>   closes six months later or at first action on the merits.